# Coalesce inside JPA query doesn't filter zero values

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KART", schema = "SCOTT")
@DynamicUpdate
@Getter
@Setter
public class Kart {

    public Kart() {
    }

    public Kart(String lsk) {
        this.lsk = lsk;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LSK", nullable = false)
    private String lsk;

    @Column(name = "KUL", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String kul;

    @Column(name = "ND", nullable = false)
    private String nd;

    @Column(name = "KW", nullable = false)
    private String num;

    @Column(name = "PSCH", nullable = false)
    private Integer psch;

    @Column(name = "SCH_EL")
    private Integer schEl;

    @Column(name = "KPR")
    private Integer kpr;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kart", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Acharge> acharge = new ArrayList<>(0);

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Kart))
            return false;

        Kart other = (Kart) o;

        if (Objects.equals(lsk, other.getLsk())) return true;
        if (lsk == null) return false;

        // equivalence by id
        return lsk.equals(other.getLsk());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (lsk != null) {
            return lsk.hashCode();
        } else {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }


}
```

And Acharge.class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_CHARGE2", schema="SCOTT")
@Getter @Setter
public class Acharge implements java.io.Serializable, Compress {

    public Acharge() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LSK", referencedColumnName="LSK")
    private Kart kart;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USL", referencedColumnName = "USl", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Usl usl;

    @Column(name = "summa", updatable = false, nullable = true)
    private Double summa;

    @Column(name = "test_opl", updatable = false, nullable = true)
    private Double testOpl;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Acharge))
            return false;

        Acharge other = (Acharge)o;

        if (id == other.getId()) return true;
        if (id == null) return false;

        // equivalence by id
        return id.equals(other.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (id != null) {
            return id.hashCode();
        } else {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }

}
```

My JPA query:

```
@Query("select k " +
        "from Kart k join k.akart a join k.acharge t on a.mg between t.mgFrom and t.mgTo and coalesce(t.summa,0) <> 0 " +
        "where t.type=1 " +
        "and a.mg in (:periods)")
List<LskCharge> getChargesByLsk(@Param("periods") List<String> periods);
```

Also I have two projections, for fetching a data:

```
public interface LskCharge {

    String getLsk();

    String getKul();

    String getNd();

    List<ChargeUsl> getAcharge();
}


public interface ChargeUsl {
    String getMgFrom();

    String getMgTo();

    @Value("#{target.usl.id}")
    String getUslId();

    BigDecimal getSumma();
}
```

Hibernate generates this query to the oracle db:

```
select kart0_.lsk as lsk1_47_, .... from scott.kart kart0_ inner join scott.arch_kart akart1_ on kart0_.lsk=akart1_.lsk inner join scott.a_charge2 acharge2_ on kart0_.lsk=acharge2_.lsk and ((akart1_.mg between acharge2_.mgfrom and acharge2_.mgto) and nvl(acharge2_.summa, 0)<>0) where acharge2_.type=1 and (akart1_.mg in (? , ? , ?))
```

As you can see, my coalesce was replaced by **nvl(acharge2_.summa, 0)**

Displaying the output:

```
List<LskCharge> lst = kartDAO.getChargesByLsk(Arrays.asList("201402", "201403", "201404"));
lst.stream().limit(30).forEach(t -> {
            log.info("lsk={} size={}", t.getLsk(), t.getAcharge().size());
            t.getAcharge().forEach(e -> log.info("usl={}, mgFrom={}, mgTo={}, summa={}",
                    e.getUslId(),
                    e.getMgFrom(), e.getMgTo(), e.getSumma()));
        }
);
```

And what we can see:

> TestAchargeDAO lsk=00000288 size=34
> TestAchargeDAO usl=040, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=1.74
> TestAchargeDAO usl=005, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=211.87
> TestAchargeDAO usl=029, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=7.31
> TestAchargeDAO usl=003, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=1461.2
> TestAchargeDAO usl=007, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=011, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=015, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=013, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=038, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=370.0
> TestAchargeDAO usl=044, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=27.0
> TestAchargeDAO usl=056, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=057, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, **summa=0.0**
> TestAchargeDAO usl=080, mgFrom=201404, mgTo=201404, summa=35.0

We see summa=zero in the output! Why?? Coalesce in JPA is not working??

I tried to change my query to this one, but it doesn't help:

```
@Query("select k " +
        "from Kart k join k.akart a join k.acharge t on a.mg between t.mgFrom and t.mgTo" +
        "where t.type=1 " +
        "and a.mg in (:periods) and coalesce(t.summa,0) <> 0 ")
List<LskCharge> getChargesByLsk(@Param("periods") List<String> periods);
```

Versions:

> spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.4.4
> hibernate-core:5.4.28.Final

**Update**
Hibernate generated query for variant with coalesce in where:

```
select kart0_.lsk as lsk1_47_, .... from scott.kart kart0_ inner join scott.arch_kart akart1_ on kart0_.lsk=akart1_.lsk inner join scott.a_charge2 acharge2_ on kart0_.lsk=acharge2_.lsk and (akart1_.mg between acharge2_.mgfrom and acharge2_.mgto) where acharge2_.type=1 and (akart1_.mg in (? , ? , ?)) and nvl(acharge2_.summa, 0)<>0
```

Comment: Can you please post the Hibernate generated query for the 2nd JPQL you tried?

Comment: pls, see an update